# Windows Equivalent of Unix Shell Script

Tags: batch-file, unix, windows-scripting

To begin, please excuse my lack of knowledge on windows batch scripting (even the basic).

I would like to ask for help on the equivalent of a working Unix script. This is the working script that I have.

```
#!/bin/bash
list=`cat view_tags`
for i in $list; do
    cleartool lsview -l -prop -full $i | grep "Last accessed" >& /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
         echo -n $i
         echo " " `cleartool lsview -reg ccase_win -l -prop -full $i | grep "Last accessed" | awk '{print $3}'`
    else
         echo $i cannot be found
fi
done
```

1. The "view tags" file contain:

   ```
   pompei.s1272.hwdig_b12.default
   dincsori.arisumf.s2637b_dig.default
   tags2
   ```
2. The output of "cleartool lsview -l -prop -full $i | grep "Last accessed":

   ```
   Last accessed 2017-11-05T11:32:13+01:00 by UNIX:UID-111234.s1272@server1
   Last accessed 2013-11-20T16:16:50+01:00 by UNIX:UID-124312.exrt@177.32.5.1
   cleartool: Error: No matching entries found for view tag "tags2".
   ```
3. The output of "cleartool lsview -l -prop -full $i | grep "Last accessed":  | awk '{print $3}'

   ```
   2017-11-05T11:32:13+01:00
   2013-11-20T16:16:50+01:00
   cleartool: Error: No matching entries found for view tag "tags2".
   tags2 cannot be found
   ```

Basically, it will execute the command, cleartool lsview -l -prop -full $i | grep "Last accessed" on each line of the file "view_tags".

If it finds a string "Last accessed" on the output, it will proceed to print the output but if not, it will say, "not found".

I really hope someone can help me on this. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Is cleartool lsview available on the windows system?

Comment: any samples of what view_tags consist of? It is difficult to try and duplicate something if not everything is available. Please edit the question and add sample data of things like view_tags and what output looks like when echo is used on the last accessed section

Comment: Hello, yes it is available. We are running Clearcase version 8.0.1.11:)

Comment: Are you insisting on a Windows batch equivalent (which would require using add-on tools, equivalent to the binary commands in your bash script), or would a PowerShell solution be acceptable (which would actually be a lot simpler, given what you appear to be looking to accomplish with your bash script)? (It appears to me that you want to take the file list from the file, and print the file name and last access time of each file, correct?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
For /f "delims=" %%A in ('Type view_tags') do (
  Set "Out=%%A can nnot be found"
  For /f "tokens=3" %%B in (
    'cleartool lsview -reg ccase_win -l -prop -full %%A ^| Find "Last accessed" 2^>Nul '
  ) Do Set "Out=%%B"
  Echo !Out!
)
```

- The first `For /f` will iterate the input file
- The 2nd one will parse the output of cleartool, getting the 3rd space delimited string of each line.

Answer (score 0):

The following batch script processing your posted "view_tags" input:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%A in (view_tags) do (
  for /f "tokens=3" %%B in (
    'cleartool lsview -reg ccase_win -l -prop -full "%%A" 2^>nul ^| find "Last accessed"'
  ) do echo %%A: %%B
) || echo %%A: Not Found
```

Should give the following output (though I'm not able to test):

```
pompei.s1272.hwdig_b12.default: 2017-11-05T11:32:13+01:00
dincsori.arisumf.s2637b_dig.default: 2013-11-20T16:16:50+01:00
tags2: Not Found
```

I can eliminate one of the FOR /F loops if I use [JREPL.BAT - a regular expression text processing utility written as hybrid batch/JScript](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044):

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("view_tags") do ^
  cleartool lsview -l -prop -full "%%A" 2>nul | ^
  jrepl "Last accessed (\S+)" "$txt='%%A: '+$1" /jmatchq || echo %%A: Not Found
```