# How to find old Clearcase views that no longuer uses?

Tags: clearcase

**Be careful I do not ask how to delete a view.**
I want to find the views that are no longer accessed by anyone.

Comment: cleartool lsview -full should show the last access time. I will post an answer later today

Comment: For example, I want to find all the registred Clearcase views that are no longer accessed since six months.

Comment: Thanks VonC, I will read and vost your post later, in the meantime, I use:ct lsview -properties -full | grep -E "^\ \ |Last\ accessed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`cleartool lsview`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lshistory.htm), more precisely the `-full` option

```
cleartool lsview -l -pro -full aViewTg
```

> With the `-full` option, reports the following additional properties:
>
> - When and by whom view-private data was last accessed
> - When and by whom a view-private object was last updated
> - When and by whom the config spec was last updated

Note that won't catch *all* usecase of a view, as mentioned in "[About the "Last Accessed" time stamp in cleartool lsview output](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21289326)"

You can combine that with "[Listing active views on UNIX](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.tutorial.doc/topics/a_list_activeviews_ux.htm)"

```
cleartool lsview -host your-computer-name
```

And you can pipe the result to describe the properties of each view.

You can see examples of such scripts in "[Windows Equivalent of Unix Shell Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43675433/6309)"

```
for i in $list; do
    cleartool lsview -l -prop -full $i | grep "Last accessed" >& /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
         echo -n $i
         echo " " `cleartool lsview -reg ccase_win -l -prop -full $i | grep "Last accessed" | awk '{print $3}'`
    else
         echo $i cannot be found
    fi
done
```